# Android Call Forwarding Number

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have been trying to figure out, How can i get the number of the one who is doing the call forwarding in android.

Doint some research with PhoneListener and TelephoneManager but to no avail.

I have this as a code snippet:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String phoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
....
....
....
```

The only Number i get is the calling number. Is it possible to get the number who forwarded the call? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am afraid that is not possible, because the call forwarding happens on the mobile carrier and it does not show up to the called device.